# Hidden button action won't change issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to disable the navigation bar button when I start the app and after I finish the process(fetching data), I enable it back but unfortunately it won't enable.

Please where would be my issue? While I'm putting `enable` to `YES` and when I debug it I can see that it enabling it to `YES`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    UIImage *searchBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search_icon.png"];
    barButtonSearch = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[searchBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchButton)];

    UIImage *menuBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu_icon.png"];
    barButtonMenu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[menuBtn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuButton)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonMenu;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonSearch;

    barButtonMenu.enabled = NO;
    barButtonSearch.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)unhide{

    if (!(barButtonSearch.enabled && barButtonMenu.enabled)) {

        barButtonMenu.enabled = YES;
        barButtonSearch.enabled = YES;
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ViewController *theInstance = [[ViewController alloc] init];


    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        _dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

    [theInstance unhide];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Err");
    }];

    [operation start];

    return YES;
   }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling `unhide` function?

Comment: Are you perhaps calling it from a background thread?

Comment: @the_UB I'm calling `unhide` from `AppDelegate` and it is running the method I can see that via debugger.

Comment: That means first your _AppDelegate_ is "enabled = YES" the buttons , but then when your views loads the _viewDidLoad_ method is "enabled = NO" the buttons. Isn't it?

Comment: I'm calling this method in the viewController. First the `viewDidLoad` method work and after the loading process finish from the `AppDelegate` I start calling the `unhide` method.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes I'm calling it from `AppDelegate`.

Comment: yes, but are you calling it from an asynchronous method in the app delegate - I presume so since you are loading data.  Try dispatching the call to `unhide` on the main queue

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm calling it after I finish asynchronous.

Comment: Please show the code where you call it

Comment: Is this your complete AppDelegate code. This is where the issue is. Where are you initializing theInstance?

Comment: I bet `theInstance` is `nil`

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala sorry I have edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there it is!

You are initializing your ViewController but that doesn't call your `viewDidLoad:` method. The `viewDidLoad:` method gets called when your ViewController is either Pushed or Presented! That is the time when the view gets loaded into the memory.

Therefore, the barButtons are never created and you are unable to see them.

So either make your network call inside the `viewDidLoad:` method of your ViewController

**OR**

`Push` the instance of your ViewController and then call the method `unhide`.

**Edit**

Since you are using Storyboards and not pushing any ViewController from AppDelegate, you need to use reference of your ViewController.

replace this in your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method

```
ViewController *theInstance = (ViewController *)[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController topViewController];
```

Comment: I want to ask something, normally I get into the viewDidLoad first which the view is pushed and then to the `[theInstance unhide]` normally shouldn't be working fine? the barButtons is created but not touchable. May you help me?

Comment: Yes, your barButtons will be disabled because you are calling the unhide method before the view gets loaded. Call the unhide method after the view get loaded. You can put breakpoints and see which method gets called first

Comment: Kindly share your code, where you push the controller

Comment: I have put the breakpoint and result as #1 `viewDidLoad` #2 `[theInstance unhide]` and #3 -(void)unhide method. It is the first page so I'm not pushing any view.

Comment: Well what I am assuming is that you are using storyboards. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, I'm using storyboards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73582/discussion-between-burhanuddin-sunelwala-and-luai-kalkatawi).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `[theInstance unhide]` from the completion block of the `AFHTTPOperation` - this will almost certainly be executed on a background queue.

All UI operations must be performed on the main queue.

You should use -

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        _dic  = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [theInstance unhide];
        });

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Err");
    }];
```

**Update**

Your main problem is that `theInstance` points to an instance of your view controller that isn't on the screen - It is just an instance you have allocated but not actually presented.

Assuming this view controller is the initial view controller loaded by your application you can get a reference to the correct instance using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController`

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is still not working. I have debug it.

Comment: Are you sure that the view controller pointed to by `theInstance` is the actual view controller that is on screen (and it isn't nil)?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure while the debug point comes to the  view controller in `IF` method.

Comment: Where do you set the value of `theInstance`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this method from the completion block of app delegate.

```
 [theInstance unhide];
```

And add some delegate function which will be activated after the asynchronous call completes its task. And add that unhide method there (In your view controller may be).